# How to deep copy structure and data of a sklearn Pipeline structure into a new variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, pipeline, deep-copy

Suppose I have defined a sklearn Pipeline structure. I need to deep-copy its structure and data into another variable so that when refitting the original one, the new variable does not change. I tried to use `clone` from `sklearn.base` in a similar way to the following code:

```
temp_pipe = Pipeline([
    ('Scaler', StandardScaler()), 
    ('LinearRegression', LinearRegression())]);
for i in iterations:
     temp_pipe.fit(X,y);
     ....
     if check_condition:
         final = clone(temp_pipe);
```

but it seems to do a deep copy of the structure, not of the data as stated [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.base.clone.html):

> `Clone` does a deep copy of the model in an estimator without actually
>   copying attached data

I know can do something like:

```
final = Pipeline([
    ('Scaler', StandardScaler()), 
    ('LinearRegression', LinearRegression())]);
for i in iterations:
temp_pipe = clone(final) 
temp_pipe.fit(X,y);
     ....
     if check_condition:
         final = temp_pipe;
```

but is there a way to deep-copy also the fitted data?

Comment: Why do you need to copy the data too?

Comment: No there is no way. And you should not do that. The meaning of this function is to save any model with some parameters that can be later used on the same OR new data.

Comment: @doctorlove I tried to explain it in my code: I am fitting different models on the same data and I want to store the best one, hence somehow I had to copy the data. It was just to avoid reinitialization at the beginning of `for` loop.

Comment: @makis you mean the `clone` function? Or which one?

Comment: yes the `clone`. Can you post the whole code?

Answer (score 3):

```py
from copy import deepcopy

estimator_deep_copy = deepcopy(pipeline)
```

Note that the purpose of `clone` is to get an unfitted/clean estimator.

Comment: A nice guide would be appreciated on why we should use deepcopy when dealing with pipelines instead of copy.copy (a shallow one).  
I assume that a pipeline can and usually contains mutable objects that a shallow copy will hold a reference to and it might lead to invisible conflicts and/or errors that don't throw a warning or an exception...

Comment: @nlhnt the reason for the `deepcopy` is exactly the one that you mentioned due to mutable. In the context of shallow copy, you can modify the state of the mutable (e.g. calling `fit` that might do this for some mutable internal objects) and it will affect the copied pipeline as well because you are pointing on the same objects.